# Transform Many to Many relation to One to Many relation

Tags: sql, database-design

I have the following tables (simplified):

```
create table dbo.Users
(
  User_Id int identity not null 
    constraint PK_Users_Id primary key clustered (Id),  
); 

create table dbo.UsersSeals
(
  UserId int not null, 
  SealId int not null,
    constraint PK_UsersSeals_UserId_SealId primary key clustered (UserId, SealId)
);

create table dbo.Seals
(
  Seal_Id int identity not null 
    constraint PK_Seals_Id primary key clustered (Id),  
);

alter table dbo.UsersSeals
add constraint FK_UsersSeals_UserId foreign key (UserId) references Users(Id) on delete cascade on update cascade,
    constraint FK_UsersSeals_SealId foreign key (SealId) references Seals(Id) on delete cascade on update cascade;
```

So I have a MANY to MANY relation between Users and Seals. One user can have many seals and on seal can have many users. I need a ONE to MANY where one user can have many seals but a seal has only one user.

Yes, I could remove the UsersSeals table and add a UserId into Seals table. However, I am using seals, the same way, with other tables.

I would like to have only one Seals tables with One to Many relation with Users tables and other tables.

Can this be done?

Comment: I don't see a relationship between `Users` and `Seals`.

Comment: I just updated my code to include the constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a separate [unique constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on the `UsersSeals` table on your `SealID` column

You then guarantee that this table is unique on `SealID`, which means that one seal can be associated with only one user but a user can have many seals.